# How to use shared library without header files in Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ndk-build, libcrypto

I have a shared lib (ex. libcrypto.so), but don't have header files.

Can I use this lib in other module?

I tried to use LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES to export header files, but It doesn't work.

This is prebuilt module:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libcrypto
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libcrypto.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And, this is module used libcrypto:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += test.c # include "openssl/crypto.h"
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(crypto_PATH)/include
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libcrypto

LOCAL_MODULE := libtest
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This is libcrypto module (boringssl):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
# Target shared library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE := libcrypto
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/include
LOCAL_ADDITIONAL_DEPENDENCIES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/Android.mk $(LOCAL_PATH)/crypto-sources.mk
LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := 9
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fvisibility=hidden -DBORINGSSL_SHARED_LIBRARY -DBORINGSSL_IMPLEMENTATION -DOPENSSL_SMALL -Wno-unused-parameter
# sha256-armv4.S does not compile with clang.
LOCAL_CLANG_ASFLAGS_arm += -no-integrated-as
LOCAL_CLANG_ASFLAGS_arm64 += -march=armv8-a+crypto
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/crypto-sources.mk
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

EDIT: Added boringssl module. I actually used `#include "openssl/crypto.h"` in test.c

Comment: You can run `ndk-build V=1` to run verbosely, which will print all the build commands that ndk-build runs. If you aren't seeing the include path at all. A likely answer is that the path is wrong. How are your two Android.mk files being included? Are you using `import-module`?

Comment: If header files exist in `$(crypto_PATH)/include`, everything is ok. But, if I remove the header source, **crypto.h** will not be finded. The header source was not exported automatically?

Comment: Anyone can help? I built it using NDK 12 with Eclipse in Ubuntu. It's ok if imported headers.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you find **crypto.h** under **include/openssl**. So, in your case, either change the `#include` statement in **test.c**

```
#include "openssl/crypto.h"
```

Or (less recommended), edit

```
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/openssl
```

Comment: maybe the answer is as trivial as `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS` ➝ `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` ?

Comment: first, I want to know whether we can use `libcrypto.so` bypass adding the header files to the project? Is it possible? I think `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` is for other purpose.

Comment: actually, I can use `dlsym` to call functions, but it's not good way. I want to use exported headers if possible.

Comment: What is "bypass"? Exported header(s) is clean and legitimate.